# Display Custom Field on Single Product Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I made a Custom Field using ACF in the product section. For every product, there should be a possibilty to add custom banner image. How can i display the custom banner image?

[This is where i would like to display it. Product page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m96ya.png)

[AFC settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gphlr.png)

[AFC settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUhNj.png)

[This is where i would like to add/edit the image in product section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0zOx.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Some more information about what/why you're trying to accomplish, and what you've tried so far, would be helpful.  There are [some tips here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about posting questions.

Comment: You should join some backend screenshots (editing your question) of the custom field that you have set in a product and also in ACF settings for this custom field? This could help us to help you… Also If you can say where do you want to display it…

Comment: are you adapt at coding - because this is just a question on displaying it in your template.

Answer (score 0):

The commenters above are correct in asking for more information to be able to help you specifically.

Generally speaking, however, what you'll want to look at is the Image Field ACF reference, specifically the [Template Usage section](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/#template-usage).